# For each integer $k\geq 3$, give an example of a finite group $G$ and a subgroup $H$ such that $|G|=k|H|$ and $H$ is not normal in $G$

Tags: group-theory

> For each integer $k\geq 3$, give an example of a finite group $G$ and a subgroup $H$ such that  $|G|=k|H|$ and $H$ is not normal in $G$.

I think the case that $k=|G|$ is not considered here.

I have doubts about the way this question is asked; by Lagrange's theorem, not every $3\leq k<|G|$ can give a respective subgroup.

Comment: The question gives us the power to construct the groups G and H, hence your concern that $k = |G|$ is misplaced.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider dihedral groups of suitable orders and remember that reflections do not generate normal subgroups in dihedral groups.